# How can I ignore a blank line in a text file using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, file-io, text-files

How can I ignore a blank line in between the data in a text file using VB.NET?

For example, I have a file with data like this

```
Line 1: 020220date20101231salesvalue52..
Line 2: 356465date20101231salesvalue52..
Line 3: Blank Line 
Line 4: **strong text**
Line 5: 356465date20101231salesvalue52..
Line 6: 356465date20101231salesvalue52..
Line 7: Blank Line
Line 8: 356465date20101231salesvalue52..
Line 9: 356465date20101231salesvalue52..
continues...
```

Comment: How are you reading the file currently?  I imagine all you have to do is check for an empty string at the right point of your processing loop and `continue` the loop (or whatever VB.NET's equivalent is).

Answer (score 1):

LINQ way (if file is not big enough)

```
  File.ReadAllLines("textFile.txt").Where(i=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a stream and use ReadLine(). Then, just check if the current line is empty and, if so, skip to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

As I have just learned about the

```
Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader("filepath")
```

method, I'ld say use that.

Then you could have a code looking like this(-ish)

```
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        if line <> ""
            list.Add(line)
        end if
```